# расстановка алгебраических знаков - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

вводится последовательность целых чисел в первой строке
вводится целое число во второй строке

путем расстановки знаков + и - получить из последовательности чисел первой строки число со второй строки

```
пример:
вводятся
123456789
200
```

и как итог получаем все возможные варианты получения числа со второй строки при помощи чисел с первой и знаков “+” и “-”:

```
123-4+5-6-7+89
123+4+5+67-8+9
1+234-5-6-7-8-9
```

посоветовали использовать itertools.product для этого, но так как использовать сторонние модули не могу, пришлось вынести ее в отдельную функцию

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def product(*args, repeat = 1):
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod) # itertools.product(*iterables, repeat=1)
    print(result)
    return result

Input = input()
number = input()
for combination in product([['+','-','']]*8):
    combination = str(combination)
    expression = combination.join(Input)
    answer = eval(expression)
    if answer == number:
        print(expression)
        break
else:
    print('NONE')
```

Помогите подкорректировать код, чтобы он работал.Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Блок в `else` выполняется, если из цикла **не** сделан выход через `break`, то есть ваш `else` выполняется всегда.

Как передать параметры в функцию из списка, как перемешать цифры со знаками:

```
for combination in product(*([['+','-','']] * (len(digits)-1))):
    d = [None]*(len(digits)+len(combination))
    d[0::2] = digits
    d[1::2] = combination
    expression = ''.join(d)
    answer = eval(expression)
    if answer == number:
        print(expression)
        found = True

if not found: print("NONE")
```

Comment: а если требуется ввод с клавиатуры, то digits = input()
number = input()?, насчет else, то он таки как раз выполнялся всегда, а весь остальной код нет)

Comment: @shiroi, в ответ добавил.

Comment: @ Alexander Zonov, если не добавлять                                                  
 else:
        print("None")
        break  он ничего не выводит, а если добавить, то none, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @shiroi, при использовании `else` подразумевается, что в цикле вы не перебираете все варианты, а что-то ищете и, когда нашли, завершаете цикл через `break`.

Comment: @ Alexander Zonov, тут как раз нужно перебирать все варианты и вывести все те, что подходят

Comment: @shiroi, поэтому `else` тут не подходит. Я, кажется, понял, какое поведение вам нужно, и добавил в ответ.

Comment: @ Alexander Zonov, а в случае если просто не существует решения? например: при помощи 123 получить 200?то он тогда должен вывести None, но если подставить проверку в цикл, то он будет всегда выдавать none

Comment: @ Alexander Zonov, и вот еще одна ошибка вылезла, что если вводить 123456789, то все нормально, а если вводить 23456789, то выдает 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+
                   ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing , значит в строке где цикл надо в скобках умножать не на 8, а на длину введенной строки?

Comment: @shiroi, надо умножать на количество знаков, а это длина строки - 1.

Comment: @ Alexander Zonov, ох, спасибо огромное за помощь, теперь разобрался)